# how to create sqlite database in ios swift without any wrapper class and use it

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am new in iOS development in swift . I need to know how can  I create a SQLite database and can use it in my application in swift code without using any wrapper

Comment: there is a lot of information on google, go and try it first, then come here for some specific problem.

Comment: I agree but not a single relevant info using swift language

Comment: quick search reveals good results like http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift etc etc

Comment: I think you missed something in my questn . Your link is using the FMDM wrapper class. And i already mentioned without using wrapper. So if any another method is there plz let me know

Comment: Why don't you study an existing wrapper, such as SQLite.swift or GRDB, and extract the raw SQLite calls from them?

Comment: Thanks @GwendalRoué will go thru this.

Comment: GRDB contains performance tests that show raw SQLite calls: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/Tests/Performance/FetchPositionalValuesTests.swift (fetching) and https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/Tests/Performance/InsertPositionalValuesTests.swift (inserting). This may also help you.

Comment: Look at the testSQLite() functions in the above links.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can try it using CoreData. Core data also stored information in default sqlite database file. 
By adding entity in .xcdatamodeld file you can directly  use sqlite database For reference you just have a look on http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial